# How to connect to a public WiFi with failing DHCP server

Tags: networking, dhcp, public-wifi

We've all experienced when you can't connect to a WiFi in a coffee shop or shopping mall - the connection is just not working. Many times, I was able to connect to the network by:

1. Checking the assigned IP address at one of my (or friends) devices that connected successfully
2. Using manual assignment of the IP address on the device that can't connect - using default gateway and subnet mask from the other device, connect to wifi without working DHCP server, and a random IP address from within that network.

Is there any way to **automatically try connecting to the WiFi with commonly used IP addresses/default gateway** (192.168.1.1, 10.0.0.1, ...) and thus try to get the internet connection to work?

Comment: You would have to write a program or script.  You could probably do it in powershell or vba.  Obviously you could do it in C, but its a much harder programming language to pick up.

Comment: @cybernard  I was hoping that someone might have already tackled this 